# try to implement the join query in Cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp, mysqli, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp and try to implement the join . or inner join query ... what i am doing right now is this

```php
$this->bindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'className' => 'Contact',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Message.user_id = Contact.user_id',
                'Message.mobileNo = Contact.mobileNo'
            )
        )
    )
), false);

return $message_details = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(),
    'fields' => array('DISTINCT mobileNo')
));
```

this query is doing **LEFT JOIN** the table .. what i want is **join** or **inner join** between two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the type of join in your belongsTo configuration, as stated in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto). The default is left, but you can use any valid join type. Simply add `'type' => 'inner'` to the configuration array, so you should get something like this:

```php
$this->bindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'className' => 'Contact',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Message.user_id = Contact.user_id',
                'Message.mobileNo = Contact.mobileNo'
            ),
            'type' => 'inner' // Simply add this
        )
    )
), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add the joins to your query without using bingModel:

```
return $message_details = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(),
    'fields' => array('DISTINCT mobileNo'),
    'joins'=>array(
        array(
            'table'=>'contacts,
            'alias'=>'Contact',
            'type'=>'INNER',
            'conditions'=>array(
                'Message.user_id = Contact.user_id',
                'Message.mobileNo = Contact.mobileNo'
            )
        )
    )
));
```